# Encoding of written out files

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, write-file

I have a tex file with:

`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

The file calls a macro that saves the content between and `\begin{something}` and `\end{something}` to a file. But the encoding of the file is not `utf8`. Is there a way to set encoding of the output file (I can rewrite the macro if necessary).

The macro is:

```
\def\@something[#1]{%
    \gdef\@somethinginclude{#1}
    \immediate\openout\@out=\@outname.tmp
    \newlinechar='15
    \begingroup \catcode`\^^M=12 %
    \let\do\@makeother\dospecials\obeyspaces%
    \@xsomething
}

\def\endsomething{%
    \endgroup
    \immediate\closeout\@out
}
```

### Edit

I have simplified the macro:

```
\RequirePackage{fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{something}
{
    \VerbatimOut{\@outname.tmp}}
{
    \endVerbatimOut
}
```

This makes the code much easier, but the encoding is still not right. It seems that the internal representation is used.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58178/3734

Comment: Is there something like `\outputencoding{latin9 or whatever}` from `outputenc` package while writing to external files ?

Comment: How are `\something` and `\@xsomething` defined?

Comment: all standard latex file writing should write just using `LICR` ie ascii TeX notation so be compatible with utf-8,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` characters with the high bit set are made active and verbatim environments don't change this. You can do it yourself:

I called this file `hernan.tex`, so the output file will be `hernan.out`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{writefile}[1]
 {\deactivateeightbit\VerbatimOut{#1.out}}
 {\endVerbatimOut}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\deactivateeightbit}{%
  \count@=127
  \loop
    \catcode\count@=12
    \ifnum\count@<255
    \advance\count@\@ne
  \repeat
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Questo è il mio testo.

\begin{writefile}{\jobname}
àèì
\end{writefile}

\end{document}
```

The contents of `hernan.out` is

```
àèì
```

If I look at it with `LESSCHARSET=ascii less hernan.out` I get this

```
<C3><A0><C3><A8><C3><AC>
```

which shows correct UTF-8.